# Weird number overlay at the bottom left of Tikzplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to create a graph using very small numbers and I think I have it working. The problem is that at the bottom left there's an overlay of text that I cannot figure out how to remove. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%graph and diagrams
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} %remember this line or the graph wont work
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth, height=15cm,
    title={$\kappa$ as Determined by Distance and Capacitance},
     xlabel={$Distance: \frac{E_0A}{d}_{(10^{-10} \cdot m^{-2}kg^{-1}s^4A^2)} $},
    ylabel={$Capacitance: C_{(nF)}$},
    label style={font=\small},
    xmin=0, xmax=.0000000007,
     ymin=0, ymax= 0.0000000016,
    xtick={0,.00000000005,...,.0000000007},
    ytick ={0.0000000002, 0.0000000004,..., 0.0000000016},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed, %remove for undashed grid%
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize,
                      /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill},
    scaled ticks=true,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=1}, 
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=1},             ]
%legend
    \legend{$1.777x + 2.7 \cdot 10^{-10}$}
%linear line
\addplot [domain=0:.0000000007, samples=100,color=blue]   {1.777*x + 0.00000000027};
%data points
\addplot +[only marks, mark=oplus, color=black] coordinates
      {(0.0000000000304,0.000000000254) (0.000000000172 ,0.000000001) (0.0000000000369,0.000000000260) (0.0000000000132,0.000000000111) (0.000000000689,0.0000000014)};
      
      
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

OP's example throws several errors, of which the first one is

```tex
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/at', to which you passed '(xticklabel cs:0.9,5pt)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

This is caused by `/pgf/number format/.cd` used in

```tex
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize,
                      /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill},
```

which changes the default path to `/pgf/number format`. It turns out that `pgfplots` uses other keys along with the keys passed to `tick label style` and those "other keys" require the default path unchanged.

Using `/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill` eliminates the errors as well as the reported "weird number overlay".

PS: When the compilation raises errors, it's better to concentrate on the first error and mention it in question description.